# Sitecore 8.2 : All Indexes are not listed in Index manager

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore8.2

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 5.

Now switching from Lucene Solr using the steps mentioned in: https://sitecorerockz.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/lucene-to-solr/

After doing all the changes when i tried to build the index the Index manager is empty as shown in this image [Indixing manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRFYa.png)

Below is the my all configuration using the .../sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx

Link: https://gist.github.com/FirozNaimAnsari/45dce0167aa608b9e14a6815270709a9

Answer (score 0):

In your config there is 1 index, a Lucene index, a custom one named mymywebsite_assets

```
<contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="mymywebsite_assets" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
```

Check if the following step is done correctly:
Navigate to the website Include folder: wwwroot\{sitename}\App_Config\Include\
Enable the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.*.config files **by removing .example** from the file name.

```
Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config.example

Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Analytics.config.example

Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core.config.example

Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config.example

Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config.example
```

In your config I see currently only the "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config"

Also on the doc.sitecore there is an walktrough specific to Sitecore 8.2 see https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html

Comment: Hi Jan Bluemink,
Thanks for your reply.

The Lucene index "mymywebsite_assets" is the commented code, Now i removed that commented but still the same issue.

I followed the link : https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html
but still the same issue.

Comment: Do you have the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core.config and the other files, without the .example extension?  and contain this files a contentSearch index configuration?

Comment: When you search in your all config, you need to have a <index id="sitecore_core_index" and so on with a SolrProvider

Comment: The Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Core.config file is present.

I am sharing the Include folder http://www.filedropper.com/include_1 and log folder.http://www.filedropper.com/logs

Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: and still the <index id="sitecore_core_index ... is not in the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx  ? if it is not there, there is something wrong with the config, file permissions? or another config file is overwriting it,

Comment: Hi Jan Bluemink,
Thanks for reply
the <index id="sitecore_core_index ... is present in the /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx.

I am uploading full Showconfig : http://www.filedropper.com/showconfig

Comment: so there is something changed. in the first config there was no index in the config.. is the Generate the Solr Schema.xml successfully done?   can you see the indexes, cores in the solr admin? else try do redo the config with the clean out of the box config files from Sitecore.

Comment: "Gist" don't allow after certain limit of characters so when i copy pasted the code it was removed that is why the first config was not not containg any index.

Using Solr admin I an see all the cores.

Answer (score 0):

All Indexes are visible in Sitecore Index Manager if you can see their configs. in ShowConfig.aspx, Just make sure that you are able to see all the required configs. If not then try Configuring it properly. I hope this Help.

Comment: I am able to see the index related configs in Showconfig.aspx  : http://filedropper.com/showconfig  but indexes are not listed in Index manager

Comment: Thanks for sharing that config file, I'm sure that you must able to see following indexes in Index Manager
sitecore_analytics_index
sitecore_core_index
sitecore_master_index
sitecore_web_index
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_master
sitecore_marketing_asset_index_web
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master
sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web
sitecore_testing_index
sitecore_suggested_test_index
sitecore_fxm_master_index
sitecore_fxm_web_index
sitecore_list_index
social_messages_master
social_messages_web

So could you please tell me which index are you referring to?

Comment: NOTE: The names which you are able to see in Index Manager, is because of the <param desc="name">$(id), and the core, which is selected is because of <param desc="core">&(id) and this id is set above,e.g <index id="sitecore_master_index">

Comment: Thanks for reply, i can see all the 15 index names in showconfir.aspx but not on the indexing manager https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRFYa.png

Comment: Ok, Since we can't see any of Index, Lets us just create a new Index, Create the file, name it as "YourProjectName.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config", somewhere in wwwroot/../AppConfig/Inculde/     I am attaching a file, Copy it and make the required changes. After this reset IIS(must) and Solr(not actually needed), you should be able to see it in IndexManager.   Sorry for replying late, I was having lunch ;) https://file.io/0bAe2C  This link is temp.

Comment: https://tmpfiles.org/download/27244/YourProjectName.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Master.config

Comment: i created a new index file using the existing one but that also did not worked.

I tried with a fresh Sitecore8.2 update 5 install in that i am able to see the indexes and able to build.

But in this project it is not working....
i am sharing include folder Include folder http://filedropper.com/include_1

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Here we again came to the same conclusion, there is something wrong with solr schema, Give me something while I figure out what's wrong

Comment: Solr is working fine for the fresh new install of Sitecore 8.2 update 5 but not for my project which is created using the same version of Sitecore. It seems something wrong with the config files or dlls of my project but i am not able to identify it :( do you want me to share some other files?

Comment: I create a diagonostic page and found that there is error
"Error activating ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 1) Request for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}"

Now I posted this error question separately at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58133072/sitecore-8-2-solr-is-not-working-giving-error

Comment: In an actual sense, It doesn't matter if solr is working or not. If you have created config of it, then it has to be visible in Index Manager, as per my knowledge. Well i'll see that question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Solr 6.6.3. Earlier this project was in Sitecore 6.X version and time to time upgrade happened and now it is in Sitecore 8.2.  I am assuming during the upgrade process some customize project contains older version dll refrence.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the below exception while debugging

> Solr Indexes Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ISolrOperations`1, key "sitecore_analytics_index" ---> Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}} No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path: 1) Request for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}} Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}. 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel. 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel. 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name. 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct. at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 376 at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, String name, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 164 at MyLibrary.test.Infrastructure.NinjectServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in C:\test_Git\Sitecore\src\test\Infrastructure\NinjectServiceLocator.cs:line 15 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 53 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 103 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize() at ASP._Page_sitecore_admin_solr_diagnostic_cshtml.Execute() in c:\test_Git\Sitecore\build\25Sep2019\Website\sitecore\admin\solr-diagnostic.cshtml:line 29