# Sitecore 8.2 : Solr is not working giving error

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore

I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 5.

Now switching from Lucene to Solr 6.6.3 using the steps mentioned in https://sitecorerockz.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/lucene-to-solr/

I created a diagnostic page to check if Solr is working or not, I got the below error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elVxs.png)) :

```
Exception Details: Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 1) Request for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}.
 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

Source Error :

```
protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) {
  return _kernel.Get(serviceType, key); 
}
```

Comment: I am using Solr 6.6.3. Earlier this project was in Sitecore 6.X version and time to time upgrade happened and now it is in Sitecore 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the below exception

> Solr Indexes Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ISolrOperations`1, key "sitecore_analytics_index" ---> Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}} No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path: 1) Request for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}} Suggestions: 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for ISolrOperations{Dictionary{string, Object}}. 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel. 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel. 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name. 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct. at Ninject.KernelBase.Resolve(IRequest request) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\KernelBase.cs:line 376 at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get(IResolutionRoot root, Type service, String name, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 164 at MyLibrary.test.Infrastructure.NinjectServiceLocator.DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in C:\test_Git\Sitecore\src\test\Infrastructure\NinjectServiceLocator.cs:line 15 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 49 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 53 at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance[TService](String key) in c:\Home\Chris\Projects\CommonServiceLocator\main\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation\ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs:line 103 at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex.Initialize() at ASP._Page_sitecore_admin_solr_diagnostic_cshtml.Execute() in c:\test_Git\Sitecore\build\25Sep2019\Website\sitecore\admin\solr-diagnostic.cshtml:line 29